# Difference between query and command in mongostat

Tags: mongodb

I wonder, what is the difference between query and command fields into mongostat output? Documentation is just says that command - number of commands. huh...

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults  locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn        set repl       time
15    161     72     *0     194     113|0         0    45g  90.8g   290m      6  Site:2.2%          0       0|0     0|0    66k   157k   105 sitename  PRI   11:25:48
```

Comment: Still no answer? I'm investigating some failed client requests that coincide with a very high peak of "commands" by looking at metrics. Still no idea what they are.

Answer (score 0):

from mongo manual ::

> `query` The number of query operations per second.
>
> `update` The number of update operations per second.
>
> `delete` The number of delete operations per second.
>
> `getmore` The number of get more (i.e. cursor batch) operations per
>   second.
>
> `command` The number of commands per second. On slave and secondary
>   systems, mongostat presents two values separated by a pipe character
>   (e.g. |), in the form of local|replicated commands.

[source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/)

Comment: yeah, i've read the documentation. But what does it mean "command"? It is not just sum of query + insert + update + getmore

Comment: hmm - if we have shard or replica set then we need to keep sync between units and that means we need to process other requests than user queries,,,,